# texi2dvi hangs with interactive prompt

Tags: tex, texinfo

I have been trying to format a manual using `texi2dvi --pdf`.  When I try to do so, it runs to what looks like completion, but then drops me into the TeX interactive prompt, `*`, with the message:

```
(Please type a command or say `\end')
```

Unfortunately, typing the end command does nothing (I just get the TeX prompt back).  My guess would be that it expects something to be terminated that is not, but I don't get a message about an open environment not being closed, nor do I get any other error message.  The last few lines of output are this:

```
Overfull \hbox (94.0258pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 2465--2465
 []    @texttt (:operator (!do ?operation) nil ((did ?operation)))[] 
[31] [32] [33] [34] [35] Chapter 7 [36] [37] Chapter 8 [38] [39] [40] [41]
Chapter 9 [42] Chapter 10 [43] Chapter 11 [44])
```

Any idea what could be wrong?  If I had to guess, I would say that pdfetex/texi2dvi expects more input for some reason, but I don't know why.

The docs indicated that texi2dvi invokes pdfetex, so I tried that, as well, but it does the same thing: runs to what looks like completion and then drops me to the interactive prompt.

`makeinfo --html` works on the same file without any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

This happened just because I was missing the `@bye` at the bottom of the texinfo file, which `pdfetex` needs, but `makeinfo` does not (having makinfo throw a warning when there's no `@bye` directive would probably be a Good Idea).

I was relying on emacs to close all the environments, but since `@bye` is not an environment closer (unlike in latex there is not a balanced begin and end of `document`), the texinfo mode in emacs couldn't figure that out.

Yes, yes, I know, I should have RTFM, but reading all the manuals is like reading all the EULAs -- no one's life is long enough! Hoping this helps someone else out.